# publishing MVC 4 app exception.., The specified path, file name, or both are too long

Tags: visual-studio-2012, publish-subscribe

I am attempting to publish a website, using the file system method.  I used this method with visual studio 2010 and I didn't run into to many problems.  But I recieved the above error when trying in visual studio 2012.  The full error is bellow...

```
Error : Copying file Service References\ACOServiceReference\FocusedReadMissionsRedux.ACOServiceReference.searchPatientbyDemographicsResponse.datasource to obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\Service References\ACOServiceReference\FocusedReadMissionsRedux.ACOServiceReference.searchPatientbyDemographicsResponse.datasource failed. The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters.
```

What am I missing or doing wrong?  Obviously a file path is too long, but is there a way I can create like path variables or something to shorten the path names?  How can I set that up?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No you can't shorten it as Windows will use the fully qualified name (C:\aaa\aaa...).

Two solutions:

1. Shorten your namespace (`FocusedReadMissionsRedux.ACOServiceReference.searchPatientbyDemographicsResponse.datasource`)
2. Change the location of your project (ie D:\Code\ProjectOne)

Comment: The only problem is that is a generated namespace for a service reference.  I may have to rename my service reference to ASR or something.

Comment: Thanks for this... moving my project to a location closer to the top level drive fixed my problem. I kinda figured as much, but I wanted to see if there was some other workarounds first.

Answer (score 5):

I was able to solve this problem on my project by navigating to the files under the service reference then under Reference.svcmap. Select each one of them and change the build action from Content to none. These files aren't usually needed for the app so they don't need to be published.

Comment: This worked for me when all other answers I had found for this problem (mainly various ways of changing the temp path) failed. Thank you for this!

Comment: Indeed! Thanks a lot for this answer, easiest way to solve this. :)